# Learn Silverlight or WPF first?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

It seems that Silverlight/WPF are the long term future for user interface development with .NET. This is great because as I can see the advantage of reusing XAML skills on both the client and web development sides. But looking at WPF/XAML/Silverlight they seem very large technologies and so where is the best place to get start?

I would like to hear from anyone who has good knowledge of both and can recommend which is a better starting point and why.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Should you learn ASP.NET or Winforms first? ASP or MFC? HTML or VB? C# or VB?

Set aside the idea that there is a logical progression through what has become a highly complex interwoven set of technologies, and take a step back and ask yourself a series of questions:

- What are your goals; how do you want to balance profit against enjoyment
- Are you short term oriented or in for the long haul
- Are you the type of person who likes to get good at something and do it a lot or do you get bored once you fully understand it?

The next and hardest step is to come to accept that any advice you are given is bound to be wrong; and the longer the time horizon the more likely it is to be incorrect. If the advice is for more than six to 12 months, the probability the advice is wildly incorrect approaches 1.

I can only tell you my story, quickly.  In 2000 I was happy as a consultant working profitably in C++ on Windows applications, writing about ASP.NET and WinForms. then I saw C# and the world turned upside down. I never went back.

Two years ago I had the same kind of revelation, only an order of magnitude bigger, stronger and with more conviction about Silverlight. Yes, WPF is magnificent, and it may be that I'm all wet about this, but I believe in my gut that Silverlight changes everything.  There was no doubt then and there is no doubt today that Silverlight is the most important development platform for Microsoft since .NET (certainly) and possibly since the switch to C++.

In a nutshell, here is why. I don't understand where its limitations are. With most platforms I do: you can do this, but you can't do that. WPF is a pretty good case in point, as was ASP.Net and WinForms and, well really everything until now.
With Silverlight, I don't see the boundaries yet. Silverlight has already leaped off the desktop onto phones, and I don't see any reason for it to stop there. Yes, it is true, it is bound by the browser, but I see that less as a jail cell than as a tank in which Silverlight will be riding over lots of terrain (it must be very late, I should go to bed).

In any case, for now, learning Silverlight is a gas, there is a lot of material on the [Silverlight.net site](http://www.silverlight.net/), and what is the very best thing about learning Silverlight is that if you don't see what you need you can holler at me and I'll make sure you get it pretty quickly.

Enjoy, good luck and the dirty little secret is you'll be fine whichever you choose. It's all just software.

-jesse

---

Jesse Liberty
["Silverlight Geek"](http://jesseliberty.com/)

Comment: "if youd don't see what you need you can holler at me"
<holler>TIFF support!</holler>

Answer (score 14):

**I'd say go with Silverlight first!**

I have programmed with WPF and Silverlight before.

But as Silverlight is a *subset* of WPF if you go in too deep and try to switch to writing Silverlight applications, you'll be scratching your heads looking for that "tag" you learned to love in WPF but is not available in Silverlight.

When you master the basic things in Silverlight first, the extra mechanism/trigger/whatever features in WPF will simply *add* to most of what you've already known.

Silverlight in WPF differs at the *features* level, not just some missing controls or animations. Take the WPF triggers mechanism for example, is not available fully in Silverlight.

So learning the smaller subset first, you can extend that knowledge to the full set later, but if you started at the full set and gets addicted to some of the niceties available, you'll have trouble down the line when someone asks you to port your designed-utilizing-WPF apps to Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will go with your advice and try out Silverlight first.

Answer (score 7):

**I'll go against the grain and say learn WPF first.**

Here's my reasoning:

- Much more resources are available for WPF than Silverlight, such as books, blogs, and msdn documentation

  - [WPF Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend)
- You're not dealing with a Beta, moving target
- You don't have to deal with working with only asynchronous calls
- Not limited by lack of features such as Merged Dictionaries, Triggers, TileBrushes, etc.
- You don't have to worry about re-learning to do things correctly because of lacks of features in SL

Answer (score 5):

Silverlight is a stripped down version of WPF so it should have fewer things to learn inside. On the other hand, the two platforms have different targets (web & rich client) so I guess it depends on what app you're going to build.
If you just want to learn for yourself (no app in the close future) I'd pick Silverlight because it would be less to assimilate. Still, Silverlight is pretty much a moving target, much more than WPF, so you'll have to keep up with some changes from time to time (the joys of being an early adopter :)).
WPF has lots more stuff that you will probably want to use at some point but I would wait for the needs to arise first.

Answer (score 4):

Every industry expert I've heard on podcasts, blogs and interviews recommend learning **Silverlight first** and then gradually moving to WPF which is a huge UI framework.

Silverlight is light and allows you to work on smaller subset of controls and features such that you get your head around this new UI building paradigm based on,

1. Templating
2. DataBinding
3. Styles

**Update: 07/2011**

I hate to mention this, but in recent times Microsoft has put more focus on HTML5, Javascript and CSS by bringing forward powers of IE 9 and IE 10, as well as the upcoming Windows 8.

More and more developers and CTOs are skeptical about Silverlight as a LOB application platform as the time passes by, we are suspecting Silverlight will be limited to Windows Phone and niche, domain areas like healthcare of graphics related applications rather than a regular LOB app.

As it seems right now, as of summer 2011, the future might look fragmented with more opportunities for pure web technologies (HTML5, JS and CSS) as opposed to a plugin and OS-specific UI technology.

Comment: +1 for the update.  Windows Metro is already taking precedence:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/

Answer (score 2):

I would start by learning XAML, by reading a few tutorials and playing around with XAMLPad. This will give you a feel for the basics before actually building an app.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with WPF and doing very simple control familiarizaton samples. You goal should be to learn XAML and Binding. So if you just create some basic WPF window apps will bootstrap your learning speed. Then eventually you can move to silverlight. Yeah as other mentioned here Silverlight is a subset of WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you are going to be working on. If you are working on client/server, then I would go with WPF.  If you are working in an environment where you can guarantee that .Net is installed on all of the machines, then I would go with WPF as well, because you can use what is called an XBAP, which is a WPF application that is run through the browser.

It's really up to you.  However, I would state that silverlight is not RTM yet, and WPF is.  WPF has a lot of books out on the subject, where silverlight does not.  It may be easier to get the whole Zen of WPF by reading a few of those books, and then dive into which ever one you would like to play with.

Just keep in mind that silverlight has a subset of the controls of WPF, a paired down .Net framework, and does not do synchronous calls.  As long as you know that up front, you can start learned the core of the whole foundation and tailor your practical experience later on to whichever technology is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips at [Getting started with Silverlight Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620/getting-started-with-silverlight-development)